# simulate pressing a button within a method call in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a little calculator program and I am trying to add a variable button. What I would like to do is that if the user presses the variable button I would like to automatically multiply this variable by whatever numbers were typed before. I have the method:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
```

and I have a button with a * symbol on it. Now, within the variable pressed method

```
- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender
```

I would like to simulate the pressing of the times button (*). So I have the following code for example

```
- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender{
if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
    [self operationPressed:<how to simulate pressing *???>];
}
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE after comments

It is an RPN calculator so you can put in the list of numbers as a stack and then press the operation buttons and it will do the operations on the stack from the top to the bottom. The operationPressed method:

```
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) [self enterPressed];
    double result = [self.brain performOperation:sender.currentTitle];

    self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
    self.history.text = [self.history.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
}
```

so when an operation is pressed it is send to the performOperation method which then decides which operation to do. My solution (including putting in some variable values for testing is the following:

```
- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString * variable = sender.currentTitle;
    NSDictionary *testDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"4",@"x",@"10",@"y",@"2",@"z", nil];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        [self enterPressed];
    }
    id numberForVariable = [testDictionary objectForKey:variable];

    [self.brain pushOperand:[numberForVariable doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
    self.history.text = [self.history.text stringByAppendingString:variable];
    //this is working pretty good. Now i need to make sure it works when i run program given values for variables.
```

}

Comment: Should you really simulate pressing the button, or would it be better to just have the variable button perform the same action on the model object as the 'times' button does to do the multiply?

Comment: Yeah that was what I was thinking. The issue is that I don't know how to pass the correct parameter to the method. The operationPressed method has as its argument a UIButton but I am not sure how to pass that parameter into the method in code.

Comment: Post more of the code. Show `operatorPressed`'s implementation

Comment: Just pass nil as the sender value. Or make another method without a sender parameter and have your button method call that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` where `button` refers to your 'times button'.

Comment: Ok I will try this but I am not sure how to describe my "times" button in the method.

Comment: A way to do this would be to use a property for your UIButton.

Comment: hmmmmm, can you please elaborate? I am a bit of a beginner with objective C so I am not 100% well versed with properties. I managed to do it a different way but I am still interested in finding out how to do this because I can see this being useful potentially later.

Answer (score 0):

So the `operationPressed` message checks what the sender is to decide what operation to perform? I think that's probably not a good design.

But, can you look at the implementation of `operationPressed` and see what it does if the button is the `*` button? Instead of calling `operationPressed` you should just do what `operationPressed` does in the case you want.

Alternatively, if you want to pursue this path and just get ahold of the right button, `operationPressed` must have a way to access the buttons for comparison, right? You should be able to access the button you need in the same way.

Comment: I added more of the code as requested. I was able to sort of solve it but not sure if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

assuming OperationPressed takes a UIButton can't you simply say

```
 [self operationPressed:sender];
```

Comment: The way I read it `operationPressed` is used for all the buttons and it decides what operation to do based on which UIButton object you pass it. So if you just send `sender` it will not do the same thing as it would when the `*` button is pressed.

Comment: No it wouldn't because it is passed a different object, this will need to be catered for in the code

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it
just create an object of the *(star) button, then in the Variable pressed methood

```
IBOutlet UIButton *starBtn_Obj;

- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender{
if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
[self operationPressed:starBtn_Obj];
}
```

this will exectue the operationPressed methood as if the *(star button was pressed).